# Не Изменяется Шрифт

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Не изменяется шрифт в текстовом поле.Подзкажите что-делать.
Вот код:

```
from tkinter import*

def allrezum():
    win = Toplevel(root,relief=SUNKEN,bd=10,bg="lightblue")
    win.title("Дочернее окно")
    win.minsize(width=400,height=200) 
def obnov():
    tex.configure(font="Verdana"+a[sca1.get()])

root = Tk()

m = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=m)

fm = Menu(m)
m.add_cascade(label="Резюме",menu=fm)
fm.add_command(label="Все резюме", command = allrezum) 

lab1 = Label(root, text="Новое Резюме", font="Arial 22")
lab2 = Label(root, text="Имя", font="Arial 18")
ent1 = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3)
lab3 = Label(root, text="Фамилия", font="Arial 18")
ent2 = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3)
lab4 = Label(root, text="Город", font="Arial 18")
lab5 = Label(root, text="Страна", font="Arial 18")
lab6 = Label(root, text="Технологический Стек", font="Arial 18")
lab7 = Label(root, text="Должность", font="Arial 18")
ent3 = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3)
lab8 = Label(root, text="Уровень Английского", font="Arial 18")
lab9 = Label(root, text="Комментарии", font="Arial 18")
frame2=Frame(root,bg='red',bd=5)
sca1 = Scale(root,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=200,
             from_=10,to=22,tickinterval=2,resolution=2)
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'10',11,'12',13,'14',15,'16',17,'18',19,'20',21,'22']
sca1.bind("ButtonRelease",obnov)
tex = Text(frame2,width=20,height=5,
          font="Verdana"+a[sca1.get()],
          wrap=WORD) 
scr = Scrollbar(frame2,command=tex.yview,)
tex.configure(yscrollcommand=scr.set)


sca1 = Scale(root,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=300,
         from_=0,to=100,tickinterval=10,resolution=5)
lab1.grid(row=0, column=1)
lab2.grid(row=1, column=0)
ent1.grid(row=1, column=1)
lab3.grid(row=2, column=0)
ent2.grid(row=2, column=1)
lab4.grid(row=1, column=2)

lab5.grid(row=2, column=2)

lab6.grid(row=4, column=0)

lab7.grid(row=4, column=2)

lab8.grid(row=5, column=0)

lab9.grid(row=4, column=2)
sca1.grid(row=6, column=1)
frame2.grid(row=5, column=1)
scr.pack(side='right', fill='y')
tex.pack(fill='both')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного поменял код:

```
def obnov(event):
    tex.configure(font="Verdana "+str(8 + sca1.get()//5)) # Размер шрифта от 8, изменение размера шрифта на 1 пт на каждые 5 единиц

...

tex = Text(frame2,width=20,height=5,
          font="Verdana "+str(8 + sca1.get()//5),
          wrap=WORD)

...

sca1 = Scale(root,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=300,
         from_=0,to=100,tickinterval=10,resolution=5, command=obnov)  # функция реакции на перемещение прописана здесь

...    

# sca1.bind("ButtonRelease", obnov) # Убрал
```

Что интересно, размер шрифта влияет на размер текстового поля (видимо, потому что размер текстового поля задается в символах) и на размер окна, что не очень удобно.

Чтобы такое не происходило, лучше задавать размер не для текстового поля, а для фрейма, в котором лежат текстовое поле и полоса прокрутки, и отключать автоматическое изменение размеров фрейма:

```
frame2=Frame(root,bg='red',bd=5, width=300, height=200) # Прописал размеры фрейма (в пикселях)
frame2.pack_propagate(False)

...

tex = Text(frame2, # Убрал размеры
          font="Verdana "+str(8 + sca1.get()//5),
          wrap=WORD)
```

Если бы элементы в фрейме были размещены с помощью `grid`, нужно было бы использовать `frame2.grid_propagate(False)`.